# My two-dimensional Sobol points seem wrong (from the scipy qmc module)

Tags: python, random, scipy

I'm using the qmc module from scipy to generate a Sobol sequence of 1024 2d points in this fashion:

```
        sampler = qmc.Sobol(d=2, scramble=False)
        sample = sampler.random_base2(10)
        points = torch.tensor(sample)
```

But when I plot these points using

```
    points = points.numpy()
    plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], s= 0.2)
```

I get a figure that looks like this:

[image]

This seems totally wrong (compare this to the figure in [the Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is sample scaled?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Sorry, it's a typo. Edited

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using the default `scramble=True`?  With `scramble=True`, the plot looks like you would expect.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I want reproduceability, it seems scramble=True destroys that.

Comment: Try setting the `seed` parameter of [`Sobol`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.Sobol.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You're right, but in my code I draw sample multiple times (every epoch). If I set the seed, I get the same points every sample. If I don't and set `scramble=True` I get different points every sample. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Can you create just one `Sobol` instance with a seed, and make repeated calls to `random_base2()` on it?  Or, since `seed` can be an instance of `numpy.random.Generator`, you could reuse the same `Generator` instance as the seed each time you create a `Sobol` instance.